# Vintage sci-fi movie ending with a man left behind on a planet, with multicoloured liquids boiling in lab cylinders

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I can remember is at the end there are some people leaving this man on a planet in a cave with multiple cylinders of colored liquid boiling in his laboratory.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about it,  when you watched it, the name of the actors, why they were abandoning him?

Answer (score 17):

I take a wild guess and say that this is the *Space 1999* episode "The Metamorph" (1976), where the alien Mentor is left behind (in, as it were, a cave) on his exploding planet with his "biological computer" Psyche which featured several vats of  coloured  liquid.

Shot taken from the episode:

[image: Character alone in a lab, vertical cylinders with multicoloured liquids]